# Fullcalendar don't display backgroundColor when i set up a date with hours/minutes

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

BackgroundColor works in mode list month

List month picture:
[image]

But no working on mode "dayGridMonth".

dayGridMonth picture:
[image]

My format date is: "2022-03-07 18:00:00" or "2022-03-07T18:00:00"

BackgroundColor works without hours-minutes in mode dayGridMonth.

Do you think it's a bug?

With "2022-XX-XX" date format:

Format date normal:
[image]

I'm sure it's a bug.

Update:
[image: My CSS]

Comment: You seem to have some custom CSS changing the appearance of the calendar. I would guess that's your issue. Without that, the calendar looks like the demo [here](https://fullcalendar.io/demos), and you can see that colours are used correctly in that.

Comment: sorry, i had no overwrite CSS, i have checked that now. 
I think backgroundColor is not apply when i set up a date invalid? Which format is accept with hours?

Comment: You definitely have changed the CSS - the screenshot proves it, especially you compare it to the demo link I provided. Fullcalendar does not look like that by default. You need to fix the CSS. We cannot help you with that, unless you edit the question to show a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: `I think backgroundColor is not apply when i set up a date invalid`...what do you mean? If you give an invalid date for your event, it will not show anywhere on the calendar at all (because if the date is not valid, fullCalendar will not know where to put it).

Comment: I write: $event['start'] = '2022-03-08 00:40:00', invalid or valid?, 
 $event['start'] = '2022-03-08' works else.

Comment: Do you have discord for talking quickly?

Comment: `invalid or valid`...it's valid. `'2022-03-08' works else`...note (from my demo) that fullCalendar does display times and all-day events slightly differently, even with the default CSS. So it's possible there is still effect from the default CSS as well, but whatever changes you have made are making it more complicated to see the problem. Again, we cannot really help you easily without proper code. Please edit your question to include a [mre] of the issue, if you require further help.

Comment: `Do you have discord`...no, and that's not how Stackoverflow works anyway. We're not a free private helpdesk for you. We give our time as volunteers for _everyone's_ benefit. So if you want an answer, it will be given here, in public, for everyone to learn from. But first, that requires us to have a question which demonstrates the problem via code. We cannot fix pictures. (Note: the pictures are useful, please do not remove them. But they are not enough by themselves to make the problem fixable.)

Comment: P.S. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay contains relevant information for you

Comment: P.P.S. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn more about how Stackoverflow works and how to ask a good-quality, useful question.

Comment: I update screens post initial. With a date normal, CSS background is a style balise. No with hours.

Comment: `I'm sure it's a bug.`...yes, probably in _your_ CSS, which you still haven't shown us. It's not a fullCalendar bug, for sure, because the difference is between one visual effect which _you_ have created, and another visual effect which _you_ also have created. It looks like you've made it hide the normal bit of the fullCalendar HTML which (as per the demo) shows the coloured dot next to timed events.

Comment: I had inspected my CSS in a href, no overwrite possible sorry.

Comment: You're joking, I assume? Your whole screen is **completely** different to how fullCalendar normally looks - it's obvious if you compare it to the demos on the fullCalendar website. You must have some _extra_ CSS in your page _as well as_ the CSS provided by fullCalendar. That must contain some rules which overwrite the fullCalendar ones (whether deliberately or not). Use your browser's element inspector to see what CSS rules are actually defined on each element, and where in the CSS code they are taken from. Checking href links does not prove anything.

Comment: $event['display'] = 'block'; works

Comment: Yes, it would. Did you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay as I suggested? That will explain it works. Thanks for the screenshot of the element inspector. it shows some extra CSS as I suggested You've cut off the text a bit but it looks like the extra rules are coming from saisie and accuei CSS files? Since you've cut off the scroll bars I can't tell if there are also other rules below which could be having an effect. But it's clear that something is changing or having an effect on the `fc-daygrid-dot-event` area underneath the `a` element you've highlighted.You should focus on that

Comment: Yes i read and tried display: background, no works. But block do the job. Thx so much.

Comment: Why did you expect `display: background` to work? That would not restore the missing dot or add a solid fill. That makes the event look like a [background event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events), as the documentation clearly explains. I think you did not understand the documentation properly. `block` will add a solid fill. So it changes from the default appearance, rather than actually fixing the missing dot which was supposed to be there by default (but has somehow been hidden by your CSS). But if that's an acceptable outcome for you then I'm glad it helped.